# CollectionViewSource Live Sorting is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I have created a user control containing a ListBox which is bound through a CollectionViewSource.  The ListBox has CheckBoxes for the user to do multiple selection on. I would like the list to be sorted with the selected CheckBoxes at the top.  I am hoping for this to work as soon as the user selects or unselects something.  I can't seem to find anything thing that does this through xaml. What am I doing wrong?

In my xaml

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems"
                      Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=Selector}"
                      IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
        <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
            <System:String>IsSelected</System:String>
        </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="IsSelected"
                                 Direction="Descending" />
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CodeDescriptionText" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

and my list box

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}"
         ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, ElementName=Selector}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
```

Comment: Where is this ? "Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=Selector}"

Comment: Items is a collection in my ViewModel

Comment: If you leave out the LiveSortingProperties collection (but still set IsLiveSortingRequested to true) it will use the properties in the SortDescriptions by default.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue, and eventually I found out the problem is with the data source, and I suspect that your issue is the same as mine.

While `CollectionViewSource` can work with a number of different types of data sources, not all of them will work with live sorting. To ensure everything work smoothly, it is best to use an `ObservableCollection` of items that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the data source.

But if you have to use a custom collection class instead of `ObservableCollection`, then make sure that class implements `IList`, not just the generic `IList<>`. If you don't, live sorting will most likely be disabled. And to ensure all other areas work smoothly, I strongly advise you to also implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it as well.

No matter which collection class you use, the items contained in it still have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There are no other ways around it.

Comment: First place that mentions a live sort-able enumerable needs to implement `IList`.... I wish the docs told me that :(

Comment: This solved it for me! I was binding my `CollectionViewSource` to an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` and it wasn't working; it does appear to work if I bind to either `IList<MyClass>` or `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. As the other commenter says, this should really be more clearly stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ItemTemplate`, are you binding `bool` properties to the `Checkbox.IsChecked` properties? If you are, then you *should* be able to set that property as the `SortDescription.PropertyName` property as it *seems* that you are doing. If not, then *that* is what you need to do.

Comment: yes my Checkbox.IsChecked is bounded to the IsSelected Property.